# Python. Отформатированный вывод списков

Tags: python, list

Имеется словарь `settings` с внутренними списками.

Файл - [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/Nb8EyVvC)
Вопрос в том, как поочерёдно вывести списки в таком порядке:

`<Result>
list #1: Libreoffice Writer, Libreoffice Calc, Libreoffice Impress
list #2: Sublime Text, Code::Blocs, Терминал`

И т.д.

Если выводить все названия программ, но не сортируя, то это так:

```
from settings import IOR
root = IOR.settings["settingsWidgetCategories"]
for j in root:
    for i in j:
        if type(i) is list:
            print(i[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from settings import IOR
root = IOR.settings["settingsWidgetCategories"]
for ndx, j in enumerate(root):
    apps = []
    for i in j:
        if isinstance(i, list) and len(i):
            apps.append(i[0])
    print('list #{}: {}'.format(ndx + 1, ', '.join(apps)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in root: # получаем все подмассивы
    x = "" # формируем список программ
    for j in range(3, len(i)):
        x += i[j][0] + ","
    print("%s: %s" % (i[0], x[:-1]))
```